# SQL query to get rows by comparing data in different columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with data as follows:

[image]

I am trying to write a SQL query to retrieve the rows where the difference between Count1 and Count2 is <= 10. So, in this case I am expecting rows 1, 3, 4 are returned after executing the query.
Can you please help me with the SQL query for this?

Thanks & Regards,
Chandra Indukuri

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE`.  Is there something you don't understand about basic SQL?

Comment: Chandra, you need to go through some tutorials, basic one to get the structure of sql language. That should help you resolve basic queries

Comment: You say you are trying to write a query. Show it. How far have you got? Where are you stuck? What part of it do you have difficulties with?

Comment: I am sorry, I was playing with dates and then I was completely lost with the numbers as well. I am good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what you want

```
select * from tbl
where count1 - count2 <= 10
```